# How to get local storage in magento controller to use as available?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7

I writing a plugin to add condition into beforeLoad function of product collection. I set local storage example js to set local storage:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("inventory", "HAN");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("inventory").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("inventory");
}
```

In the magento plugin I want to get inventory value 'HAN' from local storage to use in php class. I wrote the code as below but it can't get inventory in local storage:

```
    public function beforeLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {

        $inventory = "<script>document.write(parseInt(Object.keys(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('inventory')))))</script>";
        $test = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('inventory'));</script>";

        $joinCondition[] = "e.sku = isi.sku";
        $joinCondition[] = "isi.source_code = '".$inventory."'";
        $joinCondition = implode(' AND ', $joinCondition);
        //var_dump($requestParams);
        if (!$subject->isLoaded()) {
            // you can do your customzation/custom logic with $subject object
            //addFieldToFilter('sku', 'MG-854693')
            $subject->getSelect()->join(
                    [ 'isi' => $subject->getTable('inventory_source_item') ],
                    $joinCondition,
                    []
                );
        }

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
}
```

Please help me, How to get inventory value in php class?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage** is a javascript  variable.You can get localStorage variable value directly at Controller or Any PHP file. You need to use ajax.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834997/2940291

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-get-localstorage-key-value-into-a-php-variable-If-so-how-can-we-do-it

Comment: Thank Amit Bera, I am using cookie to get inventory value. I have other problems with beforeLoad function. 1. This plugin affect to the catalog/product amin page, I want this plugin run only on frontend. How to do that? 2. The beforeLoad function not affect when the page load data from cache. How to fix for this plugin run filter product when load from cache. Thank you so much!